# Grouping records and getting standard deviation intervals for grouped records in BigQuery, getting wrong value

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery, intervals, standard-deviation

I have a SQL below which is able to get the interval average of timestamp column grouped by icao_address, flight_number, flight_date. I'm trying to do the same for standard deviation and although I get a figure, it is wrong. The standard deviation that I get back is 14.06 (look at image below to see) while it should be around 1.8.

Below is what I'm using for stddev calculation.

```
STDDEV_POP(UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp))as standard_deviation
```

Below is my SQL

```
#standardSQL

select DATE(timestamp) as flight_date, safe_divide(timestamp_diff(max(timestamp), min(timestamp),SECOND), (COUNT(DISTINCT(timestamp)) - 1))as avg_interval_message, STDDEV_POP(UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp))as standard_deviation,  
icao_address, flight_number, min(timestamp) as firstrecord, max(timestamp) as lastrecord, count(timestamp) as target_updates
from `ais-data-analysis._analytics._aoi_table`
group by icao_address, flight_number, flight_date
having avg_interval_message is not null and flight_number is not null and icao_address = '4B8E41' 
order by flight_date, avg_interval_message ASC
```

The timestamp column is what I'm trying to get the standard deviation of, of the intervals between them, it's 10 records

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STDDEV_POP(<FLOAT>)` to calculate the standard deviation as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/statistical_aggregate_functions#stddev_pop)

> **Description**
>
> Returns the population (biased) standard deviation of the values. The
>   return result is between 0 and +Inf.
>
> This function ignores any NULL inputs. If all inputs are ignored, this
>   function returns NULL.
>
> If this function receives a single non-NULL input, it returns 0.
>
> **Supported Input Types**
>
> FLOAT64
>
> **Optional Clauses**
>
> The clauses are applied in the following order:
>
> OVER: Specifies a window. See Analytic Functions. This clause is
>   currently incompatible with all other clauses within STDDEV_POP().
>   DISTINCT: Each distinct value of expression is aggregated only once
>   into the result.
>
> **Return Data Type**
>
> FLOAT64

I hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure where to add this to my query above.

Comment: Which field do you want to calculate the standard deviation?

Comment: I uploaded the original table and wrote explanation. Its on the timestamp field, I need to get the standard deviation of the intervals between each data/record.

Comment: You want the standard deviation of the interval between the max and min timestamps calculated in seconds?

Comment: the standard deviation of each interval in timestamp grouped by icao_address and flight number (similar to the one I did for average).  Sorry if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can just put the parameters you want inside the function STDDEV_POP. Just make sure that if your parameter is not a float, you should do: STDDEV_POP( CAST(your_parameter) AS FLOAT64)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205991/discussion-between-rmesteves-and-zayn-se).